# "Permission Denied" in Node on Linux, when running start-script /w local nodemon/mocha/babel-node

Tags: linux, node.js, permissions, dependencies

I'm having issues with my new linux setup - I've installed nodemon as a local dependency (NOT globally) and I'm trying to execute it from my package.json "start"-script. I'm getting this permission error.

`node` by itself works great, but as soon as I try to use `babel-node` or `nodemon` or even `mocha`, I get permission problems.

My setup is divided across 2 hard drives - node is installed on my SSD (with my OS), and my project (and it's node_modules, where I'm trying to execute `nodemon` from is on my storage-HDD.

```
sh: 1: nodemon: Permission denied

npm ERR! Linux 3.19.0-56-generic
npm ERR! argv "/usr/bin/nodejs" "/usr/bin/npm" "start"
npm ERR! node v5.9.0
npm ERR! npm  v3.7.3
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! vyggo-easyrtc@1.0.0 start: `nodemon --exec node entry`
npm ERR! Exit status 126
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the vyggo-easyrtc@1.0.0 start script 'nodemon --exec node entry'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the vyggo-easyrtc package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     nodemon --exec node entry
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs vyggo-easyrtc
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls vyggo-easyrtc
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /media/goatic/HDD/Projects/Node/vyggo-easyrtc/npm-debug.log
goatic@goatic-laptop:/media/goatic/HDD/Projects/Node/vyggo-easyrtc$
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

My secondary drive was incompatible with my linux OS in terms of permissions, as it was an NTFS partition.

I ended up moving everything to my primary drive, and of course permissions were working again, allowing me to execute local dependencies.

I guess the solution to my problem, had I relied on keeping projects on the secondary drive, would be to format it to a format compatible with Linux permissions.

Answer (score 38):

I had this problem after changing moving my project from an NTFS filesystem to linux.  I changed all the file/directory permissions to 644/755 and also set the owner/group.  That's when I started getting this error.

When I tried nodemon in the terminal, I got `command not found`.  Strange.

Reinstalling nodemon fixed it:

```
sudo npm install -g nodemon
```

Comment: This is the solution to my problem

Comment: You need to set the file you are executing to executable ```chmod 711 your/files```

Comment: this solution fixed my error; I had a functioning Windows project and Git-cloned this Repo through VSCode on a Linux machine; npm install got everything right but nodemon; I installed globally, as directions, and worked like a charm, without even reloading the project.

Comment: I had the same issue of changing from sytem from windows to linux, so I just reinstalled nodemon (locally only) and it worked as before.

Comment: Thanks, working perfect with Fedora 37

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem. In my case when I changed my operating system to Linux Ubuntu, 20.04.1 Version, reinstalling `nodemon` solved the problem.

For Linux users:

```
sudo npm install -g nodemon
```

for Windows users, open a new terminal or `cmd` prompt just write:

```
npm install -g nodemon
```

For more information check `nodemon` documentation:

[nodemon documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nodemon)

Comment: This is the solution for me. Using Fedora 37

Answer (score 4):

If you are installing in MAC Use.

```
sudo npm install -g nodemon --unsafe-perm.
```

It will work.

Answer (score 3):

I counter this problem when I git clone a project which initially created on a Windows machine, my simple solution is to delete the .node_modules directory and then run npm install, which solved my problem.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33007802)

Comment: for this error on wsl,that's it thanks :) same problem copying project from windows filesystem to wsl

Answer (score 0):

very weird, I had the same problem except I solved it by replacing `Nodemon devStart` with `nodemon devStart` and suddenly the error was gone :)