# babel cli installed as local node module does not work: permission denied

Tags: babeljs

I can't run babel-cli from my local node modules folder.

I installed babel-cli in my local node modules folder using:

```
npm install babel-cli --save-dev
```

So that I do not have to install babel globally. I can see it installed in node_modules and is added to the package.json file.

```
  "devDependencies": {
"babel-cli": "^6.18.0"
}
```

When I build using the command

```
babel app.js -o build/app.js
```

I get a message saying babel

```
The program 'babel' can be found in the following packages:
* babel-1.4.0
* openbabel
Try: sudo apt-get install <selected package>
```

I am using Ubuntu 14.4

I tried to access the babel through the script by adding

```
 "scripts": {
"babelversion": "babel --version",
 }
```

when I run the command 'npm run babelversion' I get the same error

```
sh: 1: babel: Permission denied
```

and and NPM error with exit status 126

How do I get a local babel (without installing it globally) to work?

Answer (score 6):

I had this issue and clearing then reinstalling everything worked:

```
  >> npm cache clean --force
  >> rm -rf node_modules
  >> npm install
```

**Note**: it requires two *force* commands, so make sure you only try this in a repo wherein which you're willing to reinstall everything.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, found the solution by calling the program locally, like this:

```
./node_modules/babel-cli/bin/babel.js app.js -o build/app.js
```

Comment: @Cristovo how to call? the program

Comment: Run the command above in the terminal or reinstall npm (I recommend [nvm](https://github.com/creationix/nvm))

Answer (score 0):

If you're on Linux give the Owner group execution permission. I checked on my laptop and the permissions were as such: 644 (i.e. Read-Write for Owner, Read for Group, Read for Other). So I did: chmod 744 babel.

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/109485/why-is-permission-denied-for-npm-start-using-node-dev

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chmod

http://ss64.com/bash/chmod.html

Using sudo won't make a difference.

Answer (score 0):

Just to help someone, the error might be an incompatible format of the drive. I changed from my pendrive to the /Documents inside the hdd and all the "permission denied" errors are gone.

See this post:
["Permission Denied" in Node on Linux, when running start-script /w local nodemon/mocha/babel-node](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36128086/permission-denied-in-node-on-linux-when-running-start-script-w-local-nodemon)